How can I devise a new metric to evaluate monthly loss prevention performance based on historical data?
I'm reporting on loss numbers for my company every month, and I’m looking to create a metric that can clearly indicate whether we’re doing better or worse in preventing losses. The goal is to reflect not just the direction of the performance change (improvement or decline) but also the magnitude of the change.
I’m considering using the difference between a three-month moving average and the current month’s loss data as a normalized variable to assess this. I’m doing this as over time our numbers are increasing, e.g. sales numbers and loss numbers. However, I’d like to know if this is a statistically sound approach or if there are better alternatives.
What statistical methods could help me quantify our performance improvements (or declines) over time? If anyone has suggestions for a more robust metric or other ways to achieve this, I’d greatly appreciate your insights.
